SHAREPOINT INTRANET FOREX
i am building a SharePoint site and have been tasked to include a section that will display forex rates, what method can I use to do this? is there a third-party solution I can integrate to fetch current forex rates and display them on the site

There are various apps in Microsoft marketplace that might satisfy your requirement for displaying external data - there is a lot of variety of free/paid and generic/FOREX-specific. Look for "REST API" or "FOREX". Cannot recommend anything specific - that is up to you to decide what fits the need and the budget.
As we are in developer forum, I strongly advice to build your own webpart via SPFx - this way you will be able to shape your webpart to accustom your specific visual and functional needs.
Start with this great into project : Build your first SharePoint client-side web part
